Ionospheric delay calculation
I can't figure out how to calculate ionospheric delay from GNSS measurements. People write everywhere that you can determine ionospheric delay quite accurately from the difference in pseudorange measurements for two signals:
$$\text{delay} = \frac{p_1 - p_2}{1 - \frac{f_2^2}{f_1^2}}$$
But when I try to do this with real data (that is, with measurements that I got directly from my receiver, or with data from RTCM messages that a third-party base station broadcasts) I see that, firstly, in order of magnitude this is no more than a few meters (Klobuchar model gives 10-20 meters) and, secondly, I see in real data that for GPS sometimes $p_1 > p_2$, and sometimes $p_2 > p_1$, that is, the delay that I calculate with this formula sometimes turns out to be negative. I am almost completely confident in my data: I checked with the data that my receiver gave me (.ubx) and with the data that I received in the RTCM message stream from a commercial operator. Why could this be a problem? What should I check?

Shouldn't $p2$ also be scaled with $f_2^2 / f_1^2$, per this reference?

Note:

This is applicable to a dual frequency receiver. There are other methods to be used for a single frequency receiver, based on Klobuchar model, but the correction is only partial.

The correction is different for the two frequencies, L2 correction is larger because L2 frequency is lower and more prone to refraction on charged particles.

This doesn't correct for the tropospheric error. The later error depends on the viewing angle, but is much smaller in magnitude.


To compute the correction for ionospheric delay on code for frequency $L1$:
$$\Delta S _{iono, corr_{L1}} =
\left (
\frac {f^2_{L2}}
{f^2_{L2} - f^2_{L1}}
\right )
(\rho_{L1} - \rho_{L2})$$
For the GPS constellation multiply $L1$ correction by $\gamma = (154/120) ^2$ to get the correction on $L2$.
The result is always negative as:

$f^2_{L1} > f^2_{L2}$
$\rho _{L2} > \rho _{L1}$ (more delay on $L2$)

Adding this negative correction to the pseudorange shortens it.
The formula you used is not to compute a correction, but seems to be like the one used to get the estimated pseudorange, free of ionospheric delay error. The exact formula is:
$$
\rho _{iono-free} =
\frac
{\rho _{L2} - \gamma \rho _{L1}}
{1 - \gamma}
$$
with $\gamma$ as defined above. However this calculation is not recommended as more influenced by measurement errors.
Source: Understanding GPS, Principles and Applications, 2nd edition, Kaplan, Hegarty.

[1/2] First of all, thank you very much for your efforts and for a detailed answer.
but I would like to clarify my question.
i did use the wrong word. my formula is something like TEC (somehow scaled). plus some other noise and hardware delays - but I hope it's not too much, meters, not tens of meters. and it seems to me that, firstly, this value is always positive and, secondly, for one receiver and one satellite it should be almost the same for different pairs of signals. for example, if there are three signals (L1, L2, L5), then i should get almost the same values ​​in three ways.

[2/2] But in my data (from a trusted commercial RTCM-streams provider) i see that it doesn't work. Sometimes this value is negative and data with different frequencies doesn't give close values. But each of these values ​​(for a fixed pair of signals) changes over time so that it looks natural: very smooth change.
And I am confused with this. I've tryed most of my ideas and now hope that there is something specific which is very obvious for a real specialists, but not for me.

@user3711. My understanding of what you're doing is not clear, it seems you calculate the ionospheric (=TEC) corrections for pseudoranges on two frequencies, and compare the corrections with DGPS corrections for your area obtained over a RTCM link. Is that correct? Do you use SPS or PPS or the carrier phase? The DGPS corrections include both the ionospheric and other delays, but the former is 95% of the total error for the SPS method (only 10% for PPS). do you suspect a multipath problem?

[1/2] i suspect everything but nothing in particular. I've tried to process data from reference stations placed in the countryside (no high constructions around etc). and I see almost the same effects literally for all my data - from different places and for different elevation angles. For now, I do the following:

parsing RTCM messages, extracting DF394, ..., DF398, DF400 fields.
assembling data to form pseudoranges for all visible satellites and all signals.
for each satellite and each pair of different supported signals calculate TEC with the simple formula.


[2/2] 4. looking at the picture with results and crying.
I also tried to compare my calculated values with the Klobuchar model (using parameters from ephemeride files for visible satellites). The values are reasonable and differ a lot from all my calculations.

@user3711: The only explanation I can see is you're not extracting what you think from the RTCM frame. I don't know about the frame format, but do you extract at least consistent data? I mean if you observe say L1 DGPS correction for a few seconds, is the value consistent? same for L1 receiver pseudorange, etc, this is how you may pinpoint where the problem is, and can investigate the cause.
